# Why can't partial fractions expansion be "normally" done is this case?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

I've learned partial fractions but I couldn't really understand one thing. When we have a case when one of the factors has multiplicity $> 1$, we got to make a kind of "stairs". e.g.

$$\frac{1}{(x-1)(x+2)^2} = \frac{A}{(x-1)} + \frac{B}{(x+2)} + \frac{C}{(x+2)^2}.$$

But I thought $why$ couldn't it be written like this:

$$\frac{1}{(x-1)(x+2)^2} =\frac{A}{(x-1)} + \frac{B}{(x+2)^2}.$$

After some pencil and paper working, I realized it doesn't seem to work (and I don't know why!) I've been trying this for weeks, but I've got nowhere. So, if you could help me visualize a reason, I'd be grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: Essentially, you are trying to write a "proper" fraction (denominator of greater degree than the numerator) as a sum of "proper" fractions. But a proper fraction with a quadratic denominator may have numerator of degree up to $1$, and there are situations where this occurs, so you must include that possibility.

Comment: I changed the TeX displays from "inline" to "displayed" form (since each had a line all to itself). What was done was that a fraction was inside of TeX and a sum of fractions was inside of TeX, but the "$=$" between them was not! That is not proper use of TeX, and in some cases it results in mismatches of size or alignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple way to think about it is as follows: When you have a sum of rational functions, where denominators are polynomials, you always use the "commmon factor rule". You put in the denominator all uncommon factors and all common factors with the **greatest exponent**. So if you had

$$\frac{1}{{x - 2}} + \frac{1}{{{{\left( {x - 2} \right)}^2}}} + \frac{1}{{x + 1}} + \frac{1}{{{{\left( {x + 1} \right)}^3}}}$$

Upong merging the functions you'd get

$$\frac{{A\left( x \right)}}{{{{\left( {x - 2} \right)}^2}{{\left( {x + 1} \right)}^3}}}$$

Where $A$ is polynomial. But now you see you "discarded" the lower exponents. This is why you have to consider the "full" decomposition to get a satisfactory result. However, it is also useful to consider a decomposition as follows:

$$\frac{{A\left( x \right)}}{{{{\left( {x - 2} \right)}^2}{{\left( {x + 1} \right)}^3}}} = \frac{{Ax + B}}{{{{\left( {x - 2} \right)}^2}}} + \frac{{C{x^2} + Dx + E}}{{{{\left( {x + 1} \right)}^3}}}$$

i.e. you have to consider the polynomial of lower degree that you'd get when merging all the lower factors you have. For example in the first expression you'd get:

$$\frac{1}{{x + 1}} + \frac{1}{{{{\left( {x + 1} \right)}^3}}} = \frac{{{x^2} + 2x + 2}}{{{{\left( {x + 1} \right)}^3}}}$$

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it almost like your second case, but since $(x+2)^2$ is quadratic (degree 2), you'd need $Bx+C$ in the numerator: $$\frac{A}{(x-1)} + \frac{Bx+C}{(x+2)^2}$$

Generally, it's easier to do it the first way than the second way.

Comment: *This* is the kind of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: every *proper* fraction of form $f(x)/x^n$ can be written as $(c_0 + c_1 x +\:\cdots\: c_{n-1} x^{n-1})/x^{n}$. Such proper fractions form an $n$ dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$ with basis $x^{-1},\:x^{-2},\:\cdots\:x^{-n}\:$. Therefore if $n > 1$ then the single fraction $1/x^n$ does not span the whole space. The same holds true if one applies a shift automorphism $x\mapsto x+a$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you are given a rational function of the form
$$R(x)={p(x)\over (x-a)^m (x-b)^n}\ .$$
Using long division you may write
$$R(x)={q(x) \over(x-a)^m (x-b)^n} + p_1(x)\ ,$$
where now ${\rm deg}(q)< m+n$, and $p_1$ is another polynomial. This $q$ will have $m+n$ coefficients of arbitrary values; therefore any "Ansatz" with less than $m+n$ constants $A_k$, $B_k$ to be determined is doomed to be unsuccessful. But we are lucky: It is an algebraic **theorem** that the identity
$${q(x) \over(x-a)^m (x-b)^n} \equiv {A_m\over (x-a)^m}+\ldots +{A_1\over x-a} +{B_m\over (x-b)^m}+\ldots+{B_1\over x-b}$$
can be satisfied by a suitable choice of the $m+n$ indeterminate coefficients $A_k$, $B_k$.